# VLOOKUP Resulting in #REF

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have the following set up in Excel, and I am attempting to lookup the first column in the range A5:A7, and return column 8 (the rate) plus the custom rate.

[image: Current Setup]

I am using the following thus far and it returns the #REF! error.

=G11+VLOOKUP(A11,$A$5:$A$7,8)

So for instance, to in row 11, I am trying to find the word Flash under the Type in the range A5:A7, and return the rate that it has (column #8 or H).

It should result in $0.26.

I am new to Excel, so any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: range `A5:A7` has only one column, so you can't get column №8 from this range. Use this one instead `=G11+VLOOKUP(A11,$A$5:$H$7,8,0)`

Comment: The only change made is adding the 0 and expanding the range to H7?

Comment: no, I use `$A$5:$H$7` instead `$A$5:$A$7`

Comment: OH! So if the column number is not in the range, it can't select it?

Comment: yes, you can select values only from range specified in second parameter of formula (i.e. `$A$5:$H$7`)

Comment: Do you want to post that as an answer so I can select it as the answer?

Comment: I will select in 8 minutes when it allows me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this one instead:

```
=G11+VLOOKUP(A11,$A$5:$H$7,8,0)
```

Note, that I use `$A$5:$H$7` intead `$A$5:$A$7`. Second change is to add 4th parameter equals to 0. When this parameter is `FALSE` or `0`, `VLOOKUP` will only find an *exact* match. In this case, the values in the first column of `$A$5:$H$7` do not need to be sorted. But when you ommit this parameter - `VLOOKUP` searches for exact/approximate match and values should be sorted.